# Does GCP free trial credit continue if I just upgraded my billing account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing

I just signed up for Google Cloud Platform's free trial, and the clicked to upgrade my billing account because it said I needed that to be eligible for the "Always Free" program.

However, what I am not sure about is if that took away the $300 credit that I received from the free trial (I literally just signed up, so the time didn't expire or anything).

Do I still have that $300 credit? If not, is there a way to get it back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: Google terms have been updated and now the credits expire after 90 days, the right answer now is https://stackoverflow.com/a/65745613/797708

You should have the credit, it's explained on the free-tier documentation

> When you upgrade:
>
> Any remaining, unexpired free trial credit remains in your account.

https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade

Answer (score 5):

Earlier answer is outdated. As of August 17, 2020 new terms state that "users now have 90 days to use their $300 USD in Google Cloud credits." After 90 days any unused credits will expire.

For full details please see **[Supplemental Terms and Conditions For Google Cloud Platform Free Trial](https://cloud.google.com/terms/free-trial)**.